# How to simplify split, iterate.each and join in ruby? -- Ruby beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, split, loops

```
words = self.tag.split
words.each { |word| word = word.stem }
self.tag = words.join(' ')
```

For a given sentence I want to perform the `stem` action on **each individual word**.

Is there a way to simplify this code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
self.tag = self.tag.split.map(&:stem).join(' ')
```

Comment: Much better; I wonder why I always forget that? (I almost always do :( +1

Answer (score 2):

```
self.tag = self.tag.split.collect { |w| word.stem }.join(' ')
```

Not that I necessarily recommend doing so.

Comment: Doing this won't reassign the value of self.tag `a.split.collect{|word| word.reverse}.join => "sihteratset",  
a => "this are test" `

Comment: Dave, can you recommend a better approach to the base issues.  Would like to upvote that.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Not sure what you mean. I'm just not convinced that it's always beneficial for beginners to cram a lot of functionality onto a single line :)